# Button Counters HTML5 & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, counter

I have a clicker-type game coded in HTML5 and javascript which has upgrade buttons. I've made it so these buttons increase in price on each click, and show the price. The problem is that it shows the price of the previous upgrade, not the next one. This makes it so you can't actually see the price of the upgrade which you are about to buy.

Code :

```
let buttonUpgradeElem = document.querySelector(".upGradeA");

let cost = 20;

updateButtonDisplay();

buttonUpgradeElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cost = 1.05 * cost;
  count = count - cost;
  updateButtonDisplay();
  updateDisplay();

  counterPlusElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    count = count + 1;
    updateDisplay();
  });
});

function updateButtonDisplay() {
  buttonUpgradeElem.innerHTML = "+ 1 per click Cost : $" + cost;
}
```

I tried adding another EventListener, I thought it might solve the problem. It didn't end up solving the problem.

Comment: " `let buttonUpgradeElem = document.querySelector(.'.upGradeA'); " is supposed to be part of the code section, not the text. I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a small mix-up. It looks like you're updating the display before changing the cost. You gotta switch their order. Also, you were nesting event listeners, which is like putting a button inside another button – kinda confusing and unnecessary. Here's an example:

```
let buttonUpgradeElem = document.querySelector('.upGradeA');
let counterPlusElem = document.querySelector('.counterPlus'); // Assuming this is your counter button
let count = 0; // Start with zero, tweak as needed
let cost = 20;

updateButtonDisplay();

buttonUpgradeElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    count -= cost;
    cost = Math.round(1.05 * cost); // Pump up the cost
    updateButtonDisplay(); // Now show the new cost
    updateDisplay(); // Update the rest
});

counterPlusElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    count++;
    updateDisplay();
});

function updateButtonDisplay() {
    buttonUpgradeElem.innerHTML = "+ 1 per click Cost : $" + cost;
}

function updateDisplay() {
    // Do the rest of your display magic here
}
```

Now you buy an upgrade, taking the cost from your total. The cost then goes up and the button shows the new price for the next time you wanna get more. The counter button just adds one to your total.